# Importing Object from other class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I want to import an object from other class to one class.
I  followed the method of `#import "xyz.h"` in `abc` class implementation.

Any tried to add the object of `xyz` class in one method of `abc` class.

But it shows an error :

> Property 'a' not found on object of type xyz.

Can any one let me know how to import the object ?

Comment: means u need to access one class objects in other class .

Comment: use property and you can get it

Comment: Please show the actual code, it is not clear from your question if you are trying to add an object or inherit from one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the property defined in the header `xyz.h`, or elsewhere (such as in the class extension or another category)? It'll need to be in the header if you need to use the property from another object (or, if it's in a category, you need to declare the category in a header that you can import).